# Get the character before another in a string in Python

Tags: python

The thing I am trying to achieve is that I want to get the character before another one in a string. For e.g, if the string is "a0c1e2g3", I want to get what's written in the index[0] by just having the index[1] like i want to get the value of the index[0] ("a") when I only have the value of index[1] ("1"). I want it for all characters. I want the string to be extendable too. I am using python 3.10.1

Expected result:

```
a
c
e
g
```

The result I could get till:

```
0
2
4
6
```

The code I tried:

```
s = "a0c1e2g3"
for c, i in enumerate(s):
    if i.isdigit():
        alpha_before_int = c-1
        print(alpha_before_int)
        # I want to get "a", "c", "e", "g"
```

Comment: So have you tried to `print(s[alpha_before_int])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> s = "a0c1e2g3"
>>> for c, i in enumerate(s):
...     if i.isdigit():
...         alpha_before_int = s[c-1]
...         print(alpha_before_int)
...         # I want to get "a", "c", "e", "g"
... 
a
c
e
g
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`:

```
[c for c, n in zip(s, s[1:]) if n.isdigit()]
```

Or using `re`:

```
re.findall('(.)\d', s)
```

---

```
['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
```